# ES7 type hinting failure in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, phpstorm

I am using TypeScript in my project. JavaScript's array [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function has been valid since ECMA6. However, when I set my `lib` parameter in `tsconfig` to `"es6"` the following code throws a non-fatal error in the console browser.

```
['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'].includes('alpha');
```

The non-fatal error:

```
[default] /foo/bar.component.ts:157:28 
Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
```

There is a simple solution. Changing the `lib` parameter in `tsconfig` to `es7` silences the error in the console. All is well in the code.

However, PhpStorm 2016.3.2 does not recognize the solution. I continue to get a type hint error with the following message:

```
TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
```

How can I get PhpStorm to recognize that the use of `includes()` is valid?

Comment: AFAIK -- technically it's not PhpStorm that generates such error -- the `TS2339` indicates that it comes from TypeScript compiler/language services itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two fixes to the PHPStorm issue.

1. Add a new library to PHPStorm's frameworks. The simplest solution is to go to PHPStorm > Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries and add the `core-js-DefinitelyTyped` library.
2. If that does not work you can modify [Nitzan Tomer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/942852/nitzan-tomer)'s solution. If you keep the `tsconfig` `lib` value as `es7` and add his code to `polyfills.ts` both the type hinting errors in PHPStorm will be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's causing `PhpStorm` to act that way, but there's another solution which doesn't require you to use the `es7` lib.

You can polyfill this definition:

```
interface Array<T> {
    includes(item: T, fromIndex?: number): boolean;
}
```

And if your environment support this method then you're good to go.
If you are using a module system then you need to do this:

```
declare "global" {
    interface Array<T> {
        includes(item: T, fromIndex?: number): boolean;
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

To use the global agumation you put the `declare "global" { ... }` in a file, let's go with your name for it: `polyfills.ts` but you need to have a dummy export so that the compiler will compile it as a module, so:

```
export {};
declare "global" {
    ...
}
```

Then wherever you need it you just import like so:

```
import "./polyfills";
```

And it should work.

Comment: I switched the lib type back to es6 and added your code to polyfills.ts. The result was odd. The non-fatal errors now duplicate, as if both the es6 check and polyfill check are made and fail.

Comment: Where would you declare the global interface?

Comment: Check my revised answer